# Existence of bijection inducing isomorphism on stalks implies existence of isomorphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$, $Y$ be connected smooth projective $\mathbb{C}$-schemes. Let $f:Set(X)\rightarrow Set(Y)$ be a bijection of the underlying sets. Suppose that for any $x\in X$, there exists an isomorphism $O_{X, x}\approx O_{Y, f(x)}$. Does there exist an isomorphism $X\rightarrow Y$?

This is true in dimension 1 (the stalk is a field only at the generic point, so the schemes are birational thus isomorphic).

Comment: Consider $\mathbb A^1$ and $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: @Angelo but we require both to be projective

Comment: $\mathbb P^2$ and the blowup of $\mathbb P^2$ at a point provide a projective counterexample.